# R: Add values beside bars on horisontal bar plot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I've tried to add values from my vector to the right of my horizontal bar plots without success. I've tried to fix and mix some code as well on my x and y labels and its placements. Here is my code

```
a <- c(315, 149, 128, 97, 68, 49, 38, 0)
par(las=1)
par(mgp=c(4.5,1,0))
par(mar=c(5,6,4,3)+0.05)
barplot(a, horiz = TRUE, col="darkolivegreen3", 
main="Average Occupancy",
    ylab = "Hours",
    names.arg = c("0-1h", "1-2h", "2-3h", "3-4h", "4-5h", "5-6h", "6-7h", "7-8h"))
mtext(side=1, text="Minutes", line=2.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for your graph.

```
a <- c(315, 149, 128, 97, 68, 49, 38, 0)
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(0,0,0,0), las=1)
posbar <- barplot(a, horiz = TRUE, col="darkolivegreen3", 
    main="Average Occupancy",
    ylab = "", xlab="", xlim=c(0,350),
    names.arg = c("0-1h", "1-2h", "2-3h", "3-4h", "4-5h", "5-6h", "6-7h", "7-8h"))
mtext(side=1, text="Minutes", line=2.5)
mtext(side=2, text="Hours", line=3, las=0)
text(y=posbar, x=a, pos=4,labels=a)
```

[image]

Comment: No I want the values from the a vector to be to the right of the bars. My apologies if I wasn't clear enough. I edited my text for clarity

Comment: That's it! Thank you!